# Ionic2 - how to write unit test for a @Page

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm interesting in writing a unit tests for every @Page in my Ionic2 application (using angular2 and typescript).
All posts with testing angular2 application has references for writing tests for a @Component. My question is, does a @Page is similar to @Component? Can I test it which the same techniques or should I use any Ionic2 test frameworks?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

From the Ionic2 documentation (http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/adding-pages/):

> Page - an Angular component with all Ionic directives already provided, to be loaded using Ionic’s navigation system

If you have a look at the source code of the `@Page` decorator, you will see that a `Component` is set into the annotations of the class:

- https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/2.0/ionic/decorators/page.ts#L107

For such reasons, you can use the same approach to test pages than for components.